# Is it possible to join a worker node that is in a different network?

Tags: kubernetes

Consider the following scenario:

I have a master node with public ip: 13.82.237.240
The master is on a private network with ip 10.0.0.4

(This node is on a completely different network, but still connected to the internet)

I have a worker node with public ip 13.94.152.128
The worker node is on a private network with ip 10.0.1.4

Is it possible for the worker node to join the master?
If so what plugins do I need?

Comment: what tool did you use to deploy the cluster?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu kubeadm init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With kubeadm It's possible to join worker node to a cluster by using the public IP of master node. When you do kubeadm init on the master node you need to give the public IP of master node as parameter so that correct certs are generated by kubeadm because by default kubeadm will generate cert for private IP.

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=PUBLIC_IP_MASTER_NODE
```

Comment: ive tried to use kubeadm join on the public address but it just hangs (error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: abort connecting to API servers after timeout of 5m0s)

Comment: increase verbose log level and provide complete log kubeadm join -v=6. Also try to create a new token in the master and then use it kubeadm token create

Comment: wow i feel so stupid now,  (```Failed to request cluster info: [Get https://13.82.237.240:6443/api, x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.0.0.4, not 13.82.237.240```)

Comment: You need add the public IP as a parameter in kubeadm init on the master node...edited my answer to add this

Comment: After adding this I have another problem on the worker node: 
error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get "https://10.0.0.5:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).

Notice that originally I am not connecting to 10.0.05, but globally accessible IP, which however is not visible on host `ifconfig` (azure)

Answer (score 0):

as a default, kuber allows to join on some default dns 'names', like, "kubernetes", or in my case, "kubernetes-01.local", - see what it writes as "certificate is valid for" when connecting to dns;

so I just edited my /etc/hosts file on my slave ("joining") machine, adding something, like, `12.234.222.122 kubernetes-01.local`, then this error afterwards as well:

`Get "10.0.0.5:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/…": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).